# How to change CSS of selected text using Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selection

I am making an extension for Chrome browser that uses contextMenus to change CSS of the selected text.

But I am not able to access the HTML structure i.e. parentNode of the selected text as I can do very easily in this example.

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
```

If used by default in browser, this returns parentNode of the selected text that I can use to change the CSS later.

How to implement this using a Chrome Browser Extension?

Comment: In light of your bounty comment, what have you tried?

Comment: I mentioned that already in the question.. @Xan

Answer (score 6):

Since that Chrome doesn't let you interact with the element you have clicked on using the context menu, you have to create a **[content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)** that stores the last element that has been right-clicked on the page, so when the user right-clicks any element, you'll be able to use it.

First you have to create a `save_last_element.js` content script, like this:

```
var LAST_SELECTION,
    LAST_ELEMENT;

document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    LAST_SELECTION = window.getSelection();
    LAST_ELEMENT = e.target;
    // this will update your last element every time you right click on some element in the page
}, false);
```

Then you'll add it in your `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["*://*/*"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["/path/to/save_last_element.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "all_frames": true
    }
]
```

Now, when injecting a script in the page, you'll be able to use the `LAST_SELECTION` and `LAST_ELEMENT` variables to refer to the last right-clicked element and edit its CSSs or whatever you want.

In your `background.js` you should do something like this:

```
function handler(info, tab) {
    // here you can inject a script inside the page to do what you want
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: '/path/to/script.js', allFrames: true});
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": "Some title",
        "contexts": ["all"],
        "documentUrlPatterns": ["*://*/*"],
        "onclick": handler
    });
});
```

**Note that** the context menu is being registered inside a `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` listener, since context menus registrations are persistent and only need to be done when installing the extension.

And finally, inside your `script.js` file:

```
if (LAST_SELECTION) {
    // do whatever you want with the information contained in the selection object
}
if (LAST_ELEMENT) {
    // do whatever you want with the element that has been right-clicked
}
```

Comment: You can also use messaging to pass data between the injected script and the background script. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: That's slower. When the user clicks the context menu item you can inject the script without sending any message and it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to pass additional parameters, you probably want messaging, or else you would need to have a separate script for each case, wouldn't you?

Comment: Messaging is only another way of doing this kind of stuff, you can choose the method you like most. The OP's request can be solved more easily without messaging.

Comment: Isn't there a little bit simpler way to do this? I'm unable to follow this up completely..

Comment: there's no "simple" way to do this.. it's one of the weak points of google extensions

Comment: if you get error: `Error in event handler for contextMenus: Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'all_frames': Unexpected property.` it is because the property must be named: `allFrames`