# How do I change the colour of the highlighted text with the chrome extension I coded? (refer to picture)

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

Hopefully I worded my question right but I've been designing a chrome extension that helps people keep their place as they scroll while reading online. I want to be able to change the color of the highlighter using the popup window. How should I go about this?

My current code: https://github.com/ianbassmac/Placehldr

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgjoz.png

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047914/how-to-change-css-of-selected-text-using-google-chrome-extension/26085656), I assume you apply color change using contextMenu